# 既存プログラム改定についての作業ノウハウ

Tags: java, sql

業務プログラム開発に携わって5年以上、製造ラインで作業員として働いている状況です。
今の開発現場で2000年頃から保守され続けているプログラムの改定作業をやることが多くあり、経験も重なってきている状況です。
作業内容として、改定依頼(不具合事案から原因の修正)→(私)原因調査→修正という流れが主なのですが、原因調査を深く追えず、ダメ出しを頻繁に受けています。
長い年数やっても、こんな体たらくですが、自分で選んだ仕事、お客さんにご迷惑おかけしないよう努めていきたい一心ではあるのですが、うまくやれません。
ホウレンソウも下手なので、かなり注意を払っています。
指摘側からの言葉から察するに、自己注意力を問われている感じはします。
みなさん、どんな風に気を付けられていますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

なぜ自分は原因調査を深く追えないのか、その理由を考えてみてはどうでしょうか。
恐らく、あなたは自分と向き合う時期に立たされているのではないかと思われます。

頑張っているはずなのに、うまくやれないという心理状態は
本当は心の奥ではやりたくないと思っていることが多いです。

人が何か行うとき、本来「必要だから行う」のであって
「行わなければならない」というものではありません。

もしあなたが「行わなければならない」という心理状態になっているのだとしたら
現在の自分の状況や立場、これからの自分について深く考察し
「必要だから行う」という思考に切り替えていく必要があります。

一人で考えて迷ったり悩んだりした場合には、できるだけ大きな書店に足を運び
目に止まった本をかたっぱしから読むことをおすすめします。

最後に、スタックオーバーフローでは、このような質問は少々不適切なので
右上の「ヘルプ」に使い方の詳細が掲載されていますので、いちど目を通しておくと良いでしょう！

Comment: "tutinoco"さん、ご指摘の通り、「ヘルプ」を確認し、適正でない質問をしてしまったこと、申し訳なく思います。間違いを適正に指摘していただき、更に、術を差し伸べてくださりありがとうございます。「必要だから行う」思考への切り替え、体からなせるよう、日々精進していきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: お互いにがんばりましょう ^^